# How do I return multi select listbox values into a sentence using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a multi select listbox on a userform. There are 9 items in the listbox. How do I gather those selected items into a sentence?

The listbox contains reasons for returning a check. The items in the listbox are idenfiers or placeholders for a longer string, so the selection "unsigned", creates the returned string, "the check was not signed".

The user can select several reasons, so depending on the selections, I need sentence structure that formats as: "x, y, and z" OR "y and z" OR "z". (ex: "the check is not signed, the check is post-dated, and the check is a third-party check.")

It seems as though an array needs to be created from the selections, the selections counted, then an "If then" statement to create the sentence, but I'm stumped.
I can count the selected items, I can create the sentence if only 1 item is chosen, but the compound sentence stumps me.

Comment: This code uses a Dictionary to get the selected items, saves having to redimension arrays.  http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/03/vba-msforms-retrieving-listboxs.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have this function which returns an array of selected items from a listbox. I have updated from my original answer to return a delimited string instead of an array of selected items:

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As String
'returns an array of selected items in a ListBox
Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer
    selCount = -1
    '## Iterate over each item in the ListBox control:
    For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
        '## Check to see if this item is selected:
        If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
            '## If this item is selected, then add it to the array
            selCount = selCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
            tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.List(i)
        End If
    Next

    If selCount = -1 Then
        '## If no items were selected, return an empty string
        GetSelectedItems = "" ' or "No items selected", etc.
    Else:
        '## Otherwise, return the array of items as a string,
        '   delimited by commas
        GetSelectedItems = Join(tmpArray, ", ")
    End If
End Function
```

You can call this by assigning to an array:

```
Dim mySentence as String
mySentence = GetSelectedItems(MyUserForm.MyListBox)
```

From that point, you could just replace the *last* comma with a " and" and you should be all set.

Comment: While I mentioned in a comment that this solution worked, I neglected to add the check to the answer. I have used versions of this solution several times since this post and it's been a great addition to my code-set. Thanks, again!

Comment: I get an error saying that MSForms.ListBox is a userdefined type

Comment: @rohrl77 you will either have to enable reference to the Microsoft Forms library, or change that declaration to `lBox As Object`.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but since i'm in Access it didn't seem like it made sense, but changing it to `lBox As Object` works! Thanks!

Comment: MSForms is not listed in the reference library but you can find it in the References list by hitting the "Browse..." Button: it's called "FM20.dll"

Comment: It's named "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" in the References list (Office 2010), or yes you can locate the appropriate .DLL instead. Cheers.

Comment: Wonderful!  I changed the `lBox As MSForms.ListBox` to `lBox As Object` as suggested to avoid the missing library error, but I also had to change `tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.List(i)` to `tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.ItemData(i)`, as I was getting an invalid property error on that line.  Otherwise, works beautifully!  That got it working for me on Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic and I just quickly threw it together, but may work for what you're trying to do:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    If ListBox1.Selected(0) = True Then
        msg1 = ListBox1.List(0)
    End If

    If ListBox1.Selected(1) = True Then
        msg2 = ListBox1.List(1)
    End If

    If ListBox1.Selected(2) = True Then
        msg3 = ListBox1.List(2)
    End If

    MsgBox msg1 & ", " & msg2 & ", " & msg3

End Sub
```

Comment: What if there are a variable number of items in the listbox? This only *kind of* works if there are exactly 3 items.  If there are less than 3 items, it will raise error `9 Subscript out of Range`.  If there are more than 3 items, it requires additional variable declaration, concatenation, conditional statement for each potential listbox item, etc.  Additionally, it could yield ugly strings like `, , z` or `, y, `.

Comment: Like I mentioned, this was a really quick and basic example that I just put together.  The question was very specific to 9 list items, and it's very possible that the item being selected in the list box needs to return a completely different string altogether.  For instance, if the list item says "NSF" and the sentence returned needs to say "the check was returned for non-sufficient funds", which it sounds like this may be possible, and that this individual is writing a mail merge to send letters out for returned checks.  Just speculation.  Anyway, I like your solution, it's a good function.

Comment: I think it may be a little much for the user to understand depending on the skill level, so maybe a breakdown would be good.  It sounds like the asker is fairly new at this and is obviously trying to learn, which is great, but he/she may need a little more of a detailed and descriptive response.  Another option instead of an array could be a collection, which I remember preferring over arrays in vba.  I remember being irritated with having to re-dimension the array to the exact size of the array.  I rarely work with vba anymore and I'm a little rusty.

Comment: I added some more comments to my code and revised to return a delimited string instead of an array.

Comment: I have been out of the office, so I apologize for not responding sooner. I am certainly a newbie coder. I tried both replies and the second version that David provided worked the best. By only changing the final comma in the Join statement to " and ", changed all of the delimiters. Is there a way to say: If Count = 1, use the selected item; ElseIf Count = 2, use "and" for the delimiter; Elseif Count = 3, use "selected item1" & ", " & "selected item2" & ", and" & "selecteditem3"? I was using a popup error message for more than 3 selected items. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Forget the REDim array concept- can get confusing. A simple way to collect multiselect choices is the following

```
Sub SelectMulti()
picklist1 = ""
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
      Debug.Print i    ' optional 
      If picklist1 = "" Then
         picklist1 = ListBox1.List(i)
       Else
         picklist2 = ListBox1.List(i)
         picklist1 = picklist1 & ";" & picklist2
       End If
    End If
Next
Debug.Print picklist1

End sub
```