# Multiple Selection ComboBox - Mandatory Field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-office

This is my first time posting on the website, although I have found a number of answers that helped me. However, I was unable to find the answer to this specific question despite the extensive research.

- I have a form with multiple fields some which are mandatory and others that are not
- I was able to develop a code for all the mandatory fields except this one (Field1) for example.
- The difference is that Field1 is a dropdown with a checkbox where more than one can be selected.

How can I adjust this type of field for the following code?

```
ElseIf Len(Me.Category & "") = 0 Then
Cancel = True
response = MsgBox("You must enter a value in 'Category'.", vbInformation, "Mandatory Field")
Me!Category.SetFocus
```

`Category` is one of my other fields, and this code works fine, but when I change the name for Field1 the code doesn't work.

I hope I am as clear as possible, I would really appreciate some help from the community

Thanks,

Abu Fulan

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is put all the selected items into an array and then determine if the length of the array is > 0.

Although not identical, I think the accepted answer to this question (the answer with the green checkmark) can be slightly altered to give you what you want:

[How do I return multi select listbox values into a sentence using Word VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551754/how-do-i-return-multi-select-listbox-values-into-a-sentence-using-word-vba)

### edit

You could remove the array parts and still use the code:

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer
    selCount = -1
    '## Iterate over each item in the ListBox control:
    For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
        '## Check to see if this item is selected:
        If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
            '## If this item is selected, then add 1 to your selCount counter
            selCount = selCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    If selCount = -1 Then
        '## If no items were selected, return a messagebox saying this is mandatory
        msgbox "You MUST select something from the listbox."
    Else:
        '## Otherwise, don't worry about it
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate the swift reply, i had a look at the link it seems a tad bit confusing. I am completely unfamiliar with arrays.

Comment: Well how do you process the items you've selected from the listbox?  I mean, technically you could remove the array piece.  The whole idea is, if the number of selected items is greater than 1, you don't show the messagebox.  That code loops through the listbox and counts the number of selected items.  This is what you'll need to do to determine if you need to tell your users that the listbox is mandatory.

Comment: Ok makes sense so i would put this is code into a module then call it from the form and see if it is greater than 0. then show message box. So i would just change lbox as MSForms.ListBox to  lbox as field1.ListBox

Comment: No.  You would create a new module and paste the code above into it, and then call this as a function from your form and pass the listbox name into it.  So, from your form you would write something like GetSelectedItems(YourListboxName) where "YourListboxName" is the name of your listbox.

Comment: So I would write GetSelectedItems(Field1) where ListBox = Field1

Comment: Yep.  That should do it.

Comment: Didn't seem to work it also messed up my other mandatory fields. Am i doing it wrong, would I need to change the function to include my field (Field1). Also the field is a ComboBox not a listbox, i have a table called tblField1 with the dropdown set to allow multiple selection. And i put the Field1 into another table and created a link(Relationship) between the two fields. I am not sure if this gives more information.

Comment: However you determine what your selected items are (which I assume happens in a loop somewhere?), use that same process to instead add a number to a counter.  The concept is there, the logic is there, but I don't have your code so you're going to need to do a little of the work yourself.